# How to tell if a Cable is Crossover or Straight from one end

Tags: ethernet, layer1, cable

So I have an ethernet cable but I can see only one end of it. From the colors this end is **Straight**. The other end is connected to a router or switch (I don't know where it's connected because it goes inside a wall).

Is there a way to know if it's Crossover or not?

Problem is, **it works** on a laptop with Windows 10. **Doesn't work** on the same laptop with Ubuntu (Linux 3.2), **doesn't work** on a mac and **doesn't work** on a router (a Linksys). By doesn't work I mean it's not even recognised as plugged. I need to make it work on a router I have (the router's ports are all working, I tested with another cable).

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to tell if a cable is a crossover cable or a straight through cable without access to both ends. I doubt your problem has to do with cross over since it does work with Windows on a laptop, but not Linux on the same laptop because you are using the same interface for both.

It's not a very good idea to connect to a cable when you don't know where it is connected on the other end, especially when you want to connect a network infrastructure device like a router.

Why do you not know where it is connected on the other end? It is, after all, your network, and the National Electric Code requires cables to be terminated and labeled on both end and ready for use, or they are considered abandoned and must be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry bro, if you want to figure out whether it is a crossover cable or a straight one you have to check out both sides. U have to find a way to know where it is connected on the other side.